# How to get an array of numbers without looping

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I would like to create an array of numbers and then randomize those numbers.

Comment: why not use a loop? any particular reason?

Comment: I've come across this problem enough that I wanted to find out if there was another way to do it.

Comment: Do you have a source of random data that accepts length requests? If yes, get data into a ByteArray for 4*desired length bytes, and convert it into `Vector.<int>`.

Comment: @Vesper That went over my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've come up with. It does two things.

1. It gets an array from 0 to the length specified. What the main question was about.
2. It then randomizes the items in that array

   ```
   // returns [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] except shuffled
   var array:Array = getSequenceArray(10);


   /**
    * Get an array of the range of numbers from 1 to the number specified and randomize them.
    * */
   public function getRandomArray(count:int):Array {
       // this part is not looped. yay!
       var array:Array = new Array(count).map(function (item, index) { return index + 1; });

       return randomizeArray(array);;
   }

   /**
    * Randomize items in an array
    * */
   public function randomizeArray(original:Array, cloneArray:Boolean = true):Array {
       var length:int = original.length;
       var shuffledArray:Array = [];
       var newArray:Array = original.slice();
       var randomNumber:Number;

       // this is still using a loop. this loop is less of an issue than the first
       while (length) {
           randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
           shuffledArray.push(newArray.splice(randomNumber, 1)[0]);
           length--;
       }

       if (!cloneArray) {
           original.splice(0, shuffledArray.length); 
           original.push.apply(this, shuffledArray);
           return original;
       }

       return shuffledArray;

   }
   ```

Comment: so this is still using a loop

Comment: For part of it, yes. The randomize is using a loop. Any solutions to that I will accept. As for the other part, I'm happy with this line: new Array(count).map(function (item, index) { return index + 1; }).